# Fatal Error when attempting to approve/view reviews in backend

Tags: magento-1.7, fatal-error

This Fatal Error began occurring recently while attempting to approve/view reviews in the back end of our site, so we are unable to approve comments our customers have left. We are running Magento 1.7.0.2

I've hunted around the net but have not been able to find a solution.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Abstract' not found in /home/aloelife/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Form.php on line 35
```

Comment: Seems there's something else going wrong. Do you use any 3rd party extensions for reviews? Any other error messages in the system.log or error.log related to reviews?

Comment: I do not use any 3rd party extensions for reviews. I went into var/logs but these log files don't exist.
I attempted to turn on log reporting in the backend, but upon going to system > configuration, I recieve the exact same Fatal Error. It appears something is seriously wrong with our Magento installation...

Comment: Did you check if the class Varien_Data_Form_Abstract in lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php is really present? Maybe you are really missing the file?

Comment: I just checked. Currently, the file Form.php does exist, however the file path /Data/Form/Abstract.php does not exist, and the folder structure /Data/Form does not exist.... Would it be possible to grab this out of magento 1.7.0.2 installation package and drop it into my installation? What do you recommend?

Comment: Sure, if you haven't done any modifications to that folders, you can just re-upload that folder from a clean installation.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I will make a backup just in case, and re-upload the missing folder later this evening when our site is receiving less traffic. I'll report back after completing these steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The file Abstract.php somehow went missing, and dropping in a copy from a clean magento 1.7.0.2 installation package cleared up the errors that were occurring.